# Python web-crawl script, following tutorial and having issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

Following a tutorial on youtube: 
[Scraping Web Pages with Scrapy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EFnX1UkXVU)

It's old, for Python 2.x and I'm learning version 3.x. So far I've ran into a few issues that I've been able to figure out via Google. However currently I'm getting an error:

> File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw) File "/home/skeer/PycharmProjects/scrape_craigslists/scrape_cl/scrape_cl/spiders/scrape.py", line 11, in parse xpath = scrapy.selector(response) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Googling earlier I found references to other having this was due to a non-capitalized character, as if the 's' in selector should be capital. Tried that, and was greeted with an error about how scrapy.Selector module could not be found.

Here's my code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
import scrapy.selector 


class MySpider(Spider):
 name = "craigslist"
 allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
 start_urls = ["https://helena.craigslist.org/search/sad"]

def parse(self, response):
    xpath = scrapy.selector(response)
    titles = xpath.select("//p")
    for titles in titles:
        title = xpath("/body/section/form/div/li/p[@class]()").extract()    
        link = 
xpath("/body/section/form/div/ul/li/a[@href]").extract()
        print (title, link)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend learning with the [official docs](https://docs.scrapy.org), and also the [curated resources](https://scrapy.org/resources/).

For your issue, check the [official docs for Scrapy Selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html):

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MySpider(Spider):
...
    def parse(self, response):
        xpath = Selector(response)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

scrapy.selector is the module containing selectors. Try

```
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
```

however, this is not necessary because the response object already has [selector interface and an xpath method](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html), so you should do:

```
def parse(self, response):
    xpath = response.xpath
    titles = xpath("//p")
    for titles in titles:
        title = xpath("/body/section/form/div/li/p[@class]()").extract()    
        link = xpath("/body/section/form/div/ul/li/a[@href]").extract()
        print (title, link)
```

additionally, you will need a very good list of proxies if you are planning to scrape craigslist. They ban ip's quickly, specifically to prevent scraping.

Answer (score 1):

Changes the function definition:

```
def parse(self, response):
    xpath = scrapy.selector.Selector(response)
    titles = xpath.select("//p")
    for titles in titles:
        title = xpath.xpath("/body/section/form/div/li/p[@class]()").extract()
        link = xpath.xpath("/body/section/form/div/ul/li/a[@href]").extract()
        print(title, link)
```

Note `xpath("/body/section/form/div/li/p[@class]()")` -> `xpath.xpath("/body/section/form/div/li/p[@class]()")`